# MKMapView overlay does not display on map

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

My app gets the points for a route from google.  The response also contains the bounding rect.  My app creates the rect and shows the map correctly and I add the overlay.  The

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)
```

overlay is called and I construct a `MKOverlayPathView` from the points.  I have verified that the points are within the bounding rect.  However, the route overlay does not draw on the displayed map.

I have checked everything I can think of with no joy, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post code in RTF files or revert edits that include your code in the body of the post here.

Comment: In your TRTrip class boundingMapRect method, try returning `MKMapRectWorld` instead of the calculated response (and uncomment the fillColor, strokeColor, and lineWidth).

Comment: returned MKMapRectWorld and uncommend fill, stroke, and width.  Worldmap appears but no route(overlay) displayed.

Comment: If you add a simple MKCircle overlay at one of those coordinates (give it a big radius) and update viewForOverlay to return a MKCircleView if overlay is of type MKCircle, does the circle show?

Comment: at the point in viewFor overlay where I get the first coordinates (city of Boston) I create an mkcircle with a radius of 10000.0, create the circle view from that and returned the view.  Still no overlay.

Comment: It sounds like you might have more than one map view instantiated (perhaps one from IB and one alloc/init in code?) and the map view you are doing these operations on is behind the other.  Are you sure viewForOverlay is getting called?  What about adding an annotation at that coordinate?

Comment: By the way, don't create the circle overlay or test annotation in the viewForOverlay method itself.  Instead, do it in viewDidLoad for example.  We want to keep the circle/annotation test independent of the polyline.

Comment: I have updated the file at http://www.snowmintcs.com/downloads/delgateMethod.rtf which has the bounding rect code return the world view.  The view will appear method showing the add of the overlay and the view for overlay showing the creation of the circle, which is all it does and returns , there is no polyline executed.  The annotation shows for boston but the circle does not.

Comment: (Curious: Why don't you add the code to your question?  I think Anna Lear meant don't just post links to code.)  Don't know yet why the overlays aren't showing but I'll post an "answer" soon with some code suggestions since they won't fit in comments.

Comment: I tried adding the code to the question but kept getting errors. I tried to copy it out of Xcode and paste it into the question area. That is why I posted it so that it could be coumplete and I can easily provide you with whatever you need.

Comment: Is it ok if I add your latest code to the question?  I notice you deleted the code that was there previously for some reason.

Comment: Yippe!  Your code works fine and I get the same results.  I will go to school on it and play with it to make sure I understand exactly what is going on and why my original didn't work.  Hopefully I will  get back to where I was. Won't be able to do much over the weekend but will be back at it on Monday.  Will post how I make out then.  All your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get my route overlay to show on the map. I think the problem was my using the MKOverLayPathView.  It is much easier with the MKPolyline and MKPolyLineView.  Again thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know yet why the overlay isn't showing but try the following code in a fresh, new project.

In my test, I added the map view control to the xib and then connected the IBOutlet and the map view's delegate outlet to File's Owner.  Creating the map view in code will also work (just don't also add it to the xib and be sure to set the `delegate` property).

This is my test `TRTrip` class:

```
//TRTrip.h...
@interface TRTrip : NSObject<MKOverlay>
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MKMapRect boundingMapRect;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@end

//TRTrip.m...
@implementation TRTrip
@synthesize boundingMapRect;
@synthesize coordinate;
-(MKMapRect)boundingMapRect {
    return MKMapRectWorld;
}
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.3507,-71.0608);
}
@end
```

In the view controller's `viewDidLoad`, I add an `MKPointAnnotation`, `MKCircle`, `TRTrip`, and an `MKPolyline` to the map:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bostonCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.3507,-71.0608);

    //center map on Boston...
    mMapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(bostonCoord, 30000, 30000);

    //add boston annotation...
    MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    pa.coordinate = bostonCoord;
    pa.title = @"Boston";
    [mMapView addAnnotation:pa];
    [pa release];

    //add MKCircle overlay...
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:bostonCoord radius:10000];
    [mMapView addOverlay:circle];

    //add TRTrip overlay...
    TRTrip *trt = [[TRTrip alloc] init];
    [mMapView addOverlay:trt];
    [trt release];

    //NOTE:
    //Using an MKPolyline and MKPolylineView is probably easier than 
    //manually drawing lines using MKOverlayPathView.

    //add MKPolyline overlay...
    int numberOfRouteCoords = 3;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *routeCoords = malloc(numberOfRouteCoords * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
    routeCoords[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.34, -71.1);
    routeCoords[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.25, -71.05);
    routeCoords[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.3, -71.02);
    MKPolyline *pl = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:routeCoords count:numberOfRouteCoords];
    [mMapView addOverlay:pl];
    free(routeCoords);
}
```

and this is the `viewForOverlay` method:

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]])
    {
        MKCircleView *cv = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay] autorelease];
        cv.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        cv.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        cv.alpha = 0.5;
        return cv;
    }

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[TRTrip class]])
    {
        MKOverlayPathView *opv = [[[MKOverlayPathView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] autorelease];

        opv.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        opv.lineWidth = 3;

        CGMutablePathRef myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

        MKMapPoint mp1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.3507,-71.1));
        CGPoint cgp1 = [opv pointForMapPoint:mp1];
        CGPathMoveToPoint(myPath, nil, cgp1.x, cgp1.y);

        MKMapPoint mp2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.45,-71.05));
        CGPoint cgp2 = [opv pointForMapPoint:mp2];
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, nil, cgp2.x, cgp2.y);

        MKMapPoint mp3 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.3,-71.0));
        CGPoint cgp3 = [opv pointForMapPoint:mp3];
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, nil, cgp3.x, cgp3.y);

        opv.path = myPath;

        CGPathRelease(myPath);

        return opv;
    }

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineView *plv = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay] autorelease];
        plv.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        plv.lineWidth = 5;
        return plv;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

The red line on top is the `TRTrip` and the purple one on the bottom is the `MKPolyline`.

Answer (score 0):

If your example is a bit more complex then this, check if you have any calls like this:

```
[mMapView removeOverlay:overlay]
```

in the code.